# Nginx upload file response status

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I am trying to upload file using Nginx using the bellow config

```
location /attachments/upload {
           set $true 1;
           if ($true) {
                   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS';
                   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
           }

           # Pass altered request body to this location
           upload_pass   /callbackAttachment;

           # Store files to this directory
           # The directory is hashed, subdirectories 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 should exist
           upload_store /var/www/html/MYPROJECT/files 1;

           # Allow uploaded files to be read only by user
           upload_store_access user:r;

           upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_name" $upload_file_name;
           upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_content_type" $upload_content_type;
           upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_path" $upload_tmp_path;
           upload_pass_form_field "^document_id$|^unique_path$";



           # For resumable file uploads
           # upload_resumable on;
           # upload_state_store /usr/share/nginx/html/tmp_files 1;
           # upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;
           # track_uploads proxied 5s;
   }
```

## Pass altered request body to a backend

```
location /callbackAttachment {
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
           proxy_redirect off;

           proxy_read_timeout 3600;
           proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
           proxy_max_temp_file_size 5024m;
           proxy_send_timeout 3600;
           proxy_pass_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
           proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.2/attachments/move;
   }
```

I am using nginx upload for file uploading process, using a proxy pass url, it is passed on to backend.
The problem is whenever the upload is cancelled, it is not possible to track whether the upload is failed or not in the log file it showing as

```
2018/06/08 06:54:35 [alert] 5078#5078: *1 aborted uploading file "Product.tar.gz" to "/var/www/html/My_project/var/files/6/0009180116", dest file removed
```

Is it possible to pass this  alert to the proxy path url.